# Android Studio: where is the function list?

Tags: java, android

How to see the function list in Android Studio? like eclipse does.

Googled already, but didn't find any useful answer.

**EDIT**:

function list, means the list of functions of the current file.

nana's answer is exactly what I want, thx!

Comment: is it suggestion list ?

Answer (score 73):

#### On the left hand side (towards the top or bottom) click on Structure.

[image: See here]

If you don't see the tabs click on the button all the way in the bottom left corner:

[image: Toggle the tabs]